# Integrate a function over variable following normal distribution in R

Tags: machine-learning, integration

I want to integrate the inverse logit function over a variable *X*, which follows a normal distribution, X~*N*(21,7).

I'm a beginner in R so I have been trying following commands that didn't work out:

```
set.seed(0)    
y<-c(rnorm(1000, 21,7))    
min(y)    
max(y)    
f<-function(y) {inv.logit(-3.16+0.14*y)}    
for (i in 1:length(y)){    
  integrate(f, lower=min(y), upper=max(y))
}
```

Any help?

Comment: can you write your formula by mathematics?

Comment: We have f(x)=-3.16+0.14x and g(x)~N(20,7)

Comment: We want to estimate: ∫f(x)g(x)dx

Answer (score 1):

base on your comment:

\begin{align}
\int (-3.16+.014 x) f_x(x,20,7)dx &=-3.16+.14E(X)\\
&=-3.16 +.14 \times20
\end{align}

(I guess you are making a mistake somewhere)

Comment: Do i have to use Monte Carlo methods to estimate the joint probability distribution of f(x) and g(x)?

Comment: if you have just one X, there is no need to find joint distribution